# Reference Request: Introduction to step-size complexity of optimization algorithms

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

This issue has bothered me for a long time now, and it just came up again. For instance, I am reading some [notes](http://web.stanford.edu/class/msande318/notes/notes-first-order-smooth.pdf) where it says:

[image]

So they have this $(\dfrac{\kappa - 1}{\kappa + 1})^k$ factor, which turns into $1 - \dfrac{1}{k}$ for $\kappa$ large, but somehow all of this implies $O(\kappa \log(\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}))$ iteration complexity. I really cannot follow this argument, especially given that $\epsilon$ was never defined.

In other optimization related text, they conclude by saying "...therefore the algorithm converges sub-linearly or linearly". But they never define what these terms means.

**Can someone please recommend an up-to-date treatment of step-size complexity of optimization algorithms such as gradient descent?**

Comment: I think this book by Nesterov is useful: https://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Lectures-Convex-Optimization-Applied/dp/1402075537

Comment: By the way, you're interested in "iteration complexity" rather than "step-size complexity" (I have no idea what that would be.)  You should probably edit your question and title to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three recent references that might be helpful:

Beck, Amir. Introduction to Nonlinear Optimization: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications with MATLAB. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 2014.

Bertsekas, Dimitri P., and Athena Scientific. Convex optimization algorithms. Belmont: Athena Scientific, 2015.

Nesterov, Yurii. Introductory lectures on convex optimization: A basic course. Vol. 87. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.

Of these, the books by Beck and Bertsekas are much more accessible than the book by Nesterov.

It's not hard to briefly explain the $O(\kappa \log(\epsilon))$ iteration complexity from the inequality

$\| x_{k+1} - x^{*} \| \leq (1-1/\kappa) \| x_{k}-x^{*} \|$.

Let $D_{0}=\| x_{0} - x^{*} \|$, and suppose that we want to have 
$\| x_{n} - x^{*} \| \leq \epsilon$.  We have

$\| x_{n} - x^{*} \| \leq (1-1/\kappa)^{n} D_{0} $

So, we need

$(1-1/\kappa)^{n} D_{0} \leq \epsilon$.

$\log \left( (1-1/\kappa)^{n} D_{0} \right) \leq \log(\epsilon)$.

$n \log(1-1/\kappa) \leq \log(\epsilon) - \log(D_{0})$.

Using the fact that $\log(1-1/\kappa) < -1/\kappa$, we have

$n (\frac{-1}{\kappa}) \leq \log(\epsilon)-\log(D_{0})$

$n \geq \kappa \left( \log(\epsilon)-\log(D_{0}) \right) $

$\kappa \log(D_{0})$ is just a constant, so 
there will be a constant $C$ (which depends on $D_{0}$) such that if

$n \geq C\kappa \log(\epsilon)$,

then

$\| x_{n} - x^{*} \| \leq \epsilon $.

You also need to understand what linear and sublinear convergence are.  The sequence $x_{k}$ converges linearly to $x^{*}$ if

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\| x_{k+1}-x^{*}\|}{\| x_{k}-x^{*} \|}=c < 1$.

The sequence converges sublinearly to $x^{*}$ if $x_{k} \rightarrow x^{*}$  and

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\| x_{k+1}-x^{*}\|}{\| x_{k}-x^{*} \|}=1$.

Comment: Such detailed argument hidden in that single statement